# Как реализовать ввод нескольких переменных без пробелов между ними?

Tags: c++

Переменные `int` или `char`, нужно чтобы при вводе (`cin`) числа или слова, каждая его буква сохранялась в отдельную переменную, но чтобы для этого человеку не приходилось ставить между цифрами/буквами пробелы.

Comment: считайте строку, потом берите char из строки

Comment: А можно поподробней, просто я только учусь)

Comment: Для посимвольного чтения используйте `std::cin::get(переменная-char);`. После чтения проверяете прочитанный символ. Если это пробел — значит надо переходить к оформлению следующего числа или слова. И да, не забывайте между чтением и условием проверять `std::cin::eof()` для отлова конца введённой строки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @Arhad думаю, стоит оформить это в виде ответа

Comment: Так int или char? `char ch; cin >> ch;` и так вводит букву.

Comment: @selya, сделано.

Answer (score 2):

1. Для посимвольного чтения используйте либо `std::cin::get(переменная-char);`,  либо `переменная-int = std::cin::get();`, в зависимости от конкретного типа вашей переменной.
2. После чтения сразу же проверьте `std::cin::eof()` для отлова конца введённой строки.
3. После чтения проверяете прочитанный символ. Если это пробел — значит надо переходить к оформлению следующего числа или слова.